# Trouble getting started using PowerShell to generate formatted report of store registers group by store then lane

Tags: sql-server, powershell, logic, report

Like to use PowerShell if possible.

Looking to generate a report that I can save to a `CSV` that displays `POS` register CPUs by store and by lane.

Backend is a `SQL` database I'm am querying with

```
select STORE,REG,CPU from MY_REGISTERS;
```

I am free to change the query to anything necessary.

- STORE is an Int32 4 digit zero prefixed value; 0007, 0010, 0234, 1234. \
- REG is an Int32 single digit value; 1 - 10 that is the "lane" a register is in.
- CPU is a variable length string 10-24 chars.

I'm truncating the format due to limited space here but this is the general form.

A register lane may be empty and I would like a blank string to hold the place.

```
STORE REG001 REG002 REG003 REG004 REG005 REG006 REG007 REG008 REG009 REG010

0007  i5     i7     i7     i3     <blnk> <blnk> i6     <blnk> <blnk> <blnk>

0018  i6     <blnk> i3     i6     i5     i6     <blnk> <blnk> <blnk> <blnk>

0256  i7     i7     i5     i7     i4     <blnk> <blnk> <blnk> <blnk> <blnk>

1234  i5     i7     i7     i3     i7     i7     i5     i7     i4
```

I have started with multiple approaches but nothing seems to pan out.  I'm having trouble envisioning the path to a useful solution.

Have tried multiple nested for loops,  looking for changing values and pulling them out.

I've tried array and hash manipulation.

I've tried group-by functions.

My general approaches have all been around this basic idea below but I've not been able to realize it.

1. Query the DB for the data and store in $Return
2. Get a unique list of stores ($UniqueListOfStores = $Returned.store | Get-Unique)
3. Foreach $store in $UniqueStoreList get the $registerLaneValues
4. Foreach $reg in $registerLaneValues get the CPU
5. Build an object of store, register, and CPU values
6. Add that object to a higher level container (another array?)
7. Display the whole report and be able to Export-CSV

Get-Member info on my $Returned object from the DB Query.

```
   TypeName: System.Data.DataRow

Name              MemberType            Definition
----              ----------            ----------
AcceptChanges     Method                void AcceptChanges()
BeginEdit         Method                void BeginEdit()
.
.
.
ParameterizedProperty System.Object Item(int columnIndex) {get;set;}, System.Object Item(string columnName) {get;set;}, System.Object Item(System.Data.D... 

CPU               Property              string CPU {get;set;}
REG               Property              int REG {get;set;}
STORE             Property              int STORE {get;set;}
```

Some sample data:

```
PS E:\Repos\process-cmdb> $Returned

STORE REG CPU
----- --- ---
    7   1 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
    7   2 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
    7   3 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
    7   4 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
    7   5 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
    7   6 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
    7   7 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
    8   1 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
    8   2 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
    8   3 2500 MHz Celeron
    8   4 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
    8   5 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
    8   6 2500 MHz Celeron
   12   1 2500 MHz Celeron
   12   2 2900 MHz Pentium
   12   3 2500 MHz Celeron
   12   4 2500 MHz Celeron
   12   5 2500 MHz Celeron
   12   6 2500 MHz Celeron
   23   1 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
   23   2 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
   23   3 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
   23   4 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
   23   5 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
   23   6 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
   25   1 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
   25   2 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
   25   3 2500 MHz Celeron
   25   4 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
   25   5 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
   25   6 2500 MHz Celeron
   33   1 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
   33   2 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
   33   3 2500 MHz Celeron
   33   4 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
   33   5 3500 MHz Core i5-7600
   33   6 2500 MHz Celeron
```

I'm looking to better understand how to break this problem down and how to translate into a `PowerShell` script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see some sample data as it comes directly from the database.  Would you be able to provide this as an update to your question?

Comment: Thank you @Daniel.  I've updated the post with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this is what you had in mind.  First I group the data by 'Store', then loop through each of the groups and build a hashtable with the reg values as keys and the CPU values as the values.  Finally I output these hashtables as pscustomobjects which when exported to csv should be in your desired format.

```
$ConvertedData = $Return |
   Group-Object -Property Store |
   Sort-Object {[int]$_.Name} |
   ForEach-Object {
      # Create hashtable to build object
      $out = [ordered]@{}

      # Create STORE property
      $out.add('STORE', $_.Name.PadLeft(4, '0'))

      # Build each of the REG properties from 1 to 10
      foreach ($reg in 1..10) {
         # Look for a matching reg entry and set it to CPU value
         if ($matchReg = $_.group | Where-Object {$_.Reg -eq $reg}) {
            $out.add("REG$($reg.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0') )", $matchReg.Cpu)
         }
         else {
            $out.add("REG$($reg.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0'))", '<blank>')
         }
      }

      [pscustomobject]$out
   }

# Output to screen
$ConvertedData | Format-Table

# Export to csv
$ConvertedData | Export-Csv -Path .\output.csv  # Export to csv
```

OUTPUT

```
STORE REG001                REG002                REG003                REG004                REG005                REG006                REG007                REG008  REG009  REG010
----- ------                ------                ------                ------                ------                ------                ------                ------  ------  ------
0007  3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 <blank> <blank> <blank>
0008  3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 2500 MHz Celeron      3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 2500 MHz Celeron      <blank>               <blank> <blank> <blank>
0012  2500 MHz Celeron      2900 MHz Pentium      2500 MHz Celeron      2500 MHz Celeron      2500 MHz Celeron      2500 MHz Celeron      <blank>               <blank> <blank> <blank>
0023  3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 <blank>               <blank> <blank> <blank>
0025  3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 2500 MHz Celeron      3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 2500 MHz Celeron      <blank>               <blank> <blank> <blank>
0033  3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 2500 MHz Celeron      3500 MHz Core i5-7600 3500 MHz Core i5-7600 2500 MHz Celeron      <blank>               <blank> <blank> <blank>
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, that is spot on perfect in operation and your walkthrough is very much appreciated.  I have a working example and the means to better understand it.

The intermediate hash as well as your use of casting was exactly what I was missing in my attempts.  It has given me the "ah ha" moment I really needed.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Very glad to have helped :)